# validity check all files in a folder depending on the shebang

Tags: shell-script, files, shebang

I have a project with some lua and some bash files. I want to loop over all files and depending on the shebang I want to execute a validity check.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `find` and  `awk` to check the first line (your awk has to support FNR, like POSIX awks do) and add some search patterns to find (like excluding hidden folders):

```
echo "check bash files ..."
find . -not -path '*/\.*' \
  -type f -exec awk 'FNR == 1 && /^#!.*sh/{print FILENAME}' {} + | \
  while IFS= read -r f; do 
    echo "checking $f ..."
    bash -n "$f"
done
```

Note: use `IFS=` to avoid splitting filenames containing one of the `$IFS`, for example: `'a b'`